Is there a way to reset window.launchQueue?
The PWA I am trying to build retriggers the window.launchQueue-Consumer every time the App is reloaded.
I am trying to set up a Angular PWA that can handle links with the tel-Protocol. I've been following a guide from Google to set up the protocol handler in the manifest.json of my PWA.
Because the app is an Angular One-Pager and used to make calls with VoIP, I used "launch_handler": {"client_mode": "focus-existing"} to stop the app from reloading once the PWA is opened with a tel link. To still get the telephone-number I use the window.launchQueue and its setConsumer method.
My problem is, that once a launch parameter is handed to the launch queue, it is re-consumed every time I reload my PWA. Which also means the respective call will be triggered on every reload.
Is there a way to clear the launch queue and only consume the parameter once?
The code setting the Consumer inside the ngOnInit method of my app.component.ts:
if ("launchQueue" in window && typeof window.launchQueue == 'object' && 'setConsumer' in window.launchQueue && typeof window.launchQueue.setConsumer == 'function') {
  window.launchQueue.setConsumer((launchParams) => {
    if(launchParams.targetURL && launchParams.targetURL.includes('call/?number=tel')) {
      let link = new URL(launchParams.targetURL).searchParams.get('number')
      let number = link.split(':')[1]
      this.handleTelLink(number)
    }
  })
}

